# Android LicenseChecker crashes with null pointer exception

Tags: android, crash

It seems that if an Android phone is not logged in to Google Play, a checkAccess-call will throw a NullPointerException and eventually crash the application:

```
// user not logged in to Google Play
LicenseChecker licenseChecker = new LicenseChecker(...);
licenseChecker.checkAccess(...) // throws a nullpointer exception and crasches the app
```

The NullPointerException happens deep inside the Android framework in a separate thread:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: background thread
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator.verify()
```

hence there seems no way for the application to catch it and avoid the crash.

Any ideas how to avoid this crash? (t should be a legal situation not to be logged into Google Play)

The only way I can think of is to check Google Play login status prior to invoking checkAccess.

Answer (score 9):

I modified the method LicenseValidator.verify(), adding a protection check at the begining:

```
public void verify(PublicKey publicKey, int responseCode, String signedData, String signature) {
    if (signedData==null){
        handleInvalidResponse();
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: +d Ben Lee. I had the same issue. Added null check it worked. Can we redirect the user to download the Google Play store app or Google Play services app. Can u tell what is the cause of this issue, is it becoz of unavailability of Google Play Store App or becoz of Google Play Services app on the device.

Comment: The code above will cause issues when there is lack of network connectivity (say Airplane mode). Signed data will be null that time, and it will return NOT_LICENSED when it should be returning RETRY. The above code should be moved inside the IF clause which checks for the response code in the same method.

Comment: @jssingh -- I understand this is dated but I'm curious exactly how you worked around it.  It sounds like the right thing to do is to rewrite the initial IF as: if (signedData != null && (responseCode == LICENSED || responseCode == NOT_LICENSED || responseCode == LICENSED_OLD_KEY)) ...  This way if signedData is null we can still rely on a RETRY condition assuming responseCode reflects that state.

Comment: I'm going to go with this ^^^ approach and do some additional crashlytics logging around it to see what various states responseCode is coming back as.

Comment: So I've already collected enough data to say that responseCode can be RETRY or NOT_LICENSED when signedData is null.  I'm definitely sticking with @jssingh's recommendation to not just assume NOT_LICENSED.

Answer (score 3):

If you are simply trying to run your code on an android emulator, you can alternatively open and sign into the Google Play Store, which will update Google Play Services and fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm downvoting @Ben Lee's answer.

Building upon the recommendation that @jssingh made above, I went with the following solution:

```
public void verify(PublicKey publicKey, int responseCode, String signedData, String signature) {
    String userId = null;
    // Skip signature check for unsuccessful requests
    ResponseData data = null;
    if (signedData != null && (responseCode == LICENSED || responseCode == NOT_LICENSED ||
            responseCode == LICENSED_OLD_KEY)) {
        // Verify signature.
        try {
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
            sig.initVerify(publicKey);
            sig.update(signedData.getBytes());
        ....
        }
    }

    ........

    if (signedData == null) {
        Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("Licensing signedData is null - responseCode=" + responseCode));
    }

    switch (responseCode) {
        case LICENSED:
        case LICENSED_OLD_KEY:
            int limiterResponse = mDeviceLimiter.isDeviceAllowed(userId);
            handleResponse(limiterResponse, data);
            break;
        .....
    }
```

I leveraged Crashlytics logging to validate the claim that you CANNOT just assume NOT_LICENSED when signedData is null.

As a matter of fact, this is the condition I see my code taking with this additional check in place:

```
        case ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER:
            Log.w(TAG, "Error contacting licensing server.");
            handleResponse(Policy.RETRY, data);
            break;
```

Seems legit :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same problem while using "Expansion files". It might be because of server not responding well while Licence checking. So it sends "**SignedData= null and also Signature=null**", in LicenceChecker class.

Which ultimately affect in MainActivity's **onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)**. Here we get data=null. So try below code-->

```
public onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{    
    if (data != null) {
        fromWhere = data.getExtras().getInt("yourInt");
        done = data.getExtras().getInt("yourdata");
    } 
    else {
        //Your Default Value..
        fromWhere = 1;
        done = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope This will Help some one. Best Luck!!